# How to find if the value is the 1st repeated or last repeated with array formula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how many times the value was repeated in the column at that row in another column. And I wanted to do it with an array formula, so it shoots down automatically.

Here is the example

| ID | Position |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | First |
| 123 | In Between |
| 123 | Last |
| 456 | First |
| 456 | In Between |
| 456 | In Between |
| 456 | Last |

Struggling a bit with this was trying to use countifs - but that's not the right approach. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:

```
=BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(aixx,IF(aixx="",,IF(COUNTIF(A1:aixx,aixx)=1,"First",IF(COUNTIF(A1:aixx,aixx)=COUNTIF(A:A,aixx),"Last","In Between")))))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Awesome - what i was looking for . would ifs also work here ?

Comment: sure... nested `IF` can be replaced with `IFS`